# что означает название переменной в {}

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const { secret } = config;
```

Почему переменная secret в таких кавычках?

Answer (score 5):

Это пример деструктуризации объекта. То есть из объекта config берется свойство secret и присваивается в константу.

Answer (score 3):

Можешь почитать об этом вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta)